# Как вывелась эта формула

Tags: python, математика

Встретил задание по программированию: "Из чисел от 10 до 99 вывести те, сумма цифр которых равна S".

И вот само решение:

```
 s = int(input())
 for i in range(10,99):
     if((i//10)+(i%10)==s): print(i)
```

Как вывелась эта формула `(i // 10) + (i % 10) == s` ?

Comment: Там, кстати, ошибка :) range(от 10 до 99 - не включительно). Должно быть `range(10, 100)`,

Comment: ну бывает, ошибся

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Первая часть - деление на 10 нацело, т.е. первая цифра двузначного числа.

Вторая часть - получение остатка от деления на 10, т.е. вторая цифра двузначного числа.

Далее - просто их суммирование...

Например, 73

```
73 // 10 == 7
73 %  10 == 3
```

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку все целые числа из диапазона `[10; 99]` двузначные получаем такую картину:

1. `i//10` даст нам первую цифру числа.
2. `i%10` даст нам последнюю, которая также и вторая, цифру числа.

Answer (score 3):

Ответы в принципе вам дали по формуле, а я хочу предложить другую реализацию. Перебирает цикл быстрее(в 9 раз), и в цикле нет деления:

```py
s = int(input())
if 0 < s < 19:
    if s < 10:
        a = range(s+9,s*10+1,9)
    else:
        a = range(10*s-81,100,9)
    print(*a, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Ввел `18`, вывело `9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90` а должно только `99` )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, молодец, хороший тестер. :)